# Trouble Passing Data Via PrepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am trying to pass data to a `webViewController` using the `prepareForSegue` method, which looks like:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"RBOM"])
    {
        WebViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:myURL.com/Articles.asp?ID=274"]; 
    }
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Home"])
    {
        WebViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myURL.com"];
    }
}
```

Here is why my `webViewController` class looks like:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize url; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.title = @"MyURL.com";
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", self.url); <---- This is null


    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Here is the `webViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSURL *url; 



@end
```

The problem is that my URL is null. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: How is your url property declared?  Strong?  Weak?

Comment: Weak, see updated code.

Comment: @NicholasHart, you fixed it! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your UI elements it is generally ok to declare them weak because your view will retain them.  For your other ivars you want to declare them strong so that your class instance will retain them.  In this particular case your url property is weak, so the NSURL was not retained and was set to nil after prepareForSegue:'s scope went away.

Comment: I basically said the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

You are bound to run into this kind of trouble with prepareForSegue.
I suggest you keep strong instances of the data you want to pass in your source as:

```
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:myURL.com/Articles.asp?ID=274"];
```

and then in the prepareForSegue only do this :

```
destViewController.url = tempURL;
```

I have experienced similar problems before, this seems to solve it. I don't have a clear picture about the reason for this.